# Created new instance of wordpress site from Lightsail Snapshot/backup but now results in db error

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have never had to use a snapshot before but I recently had my site hacked and I am rolling back to a recent snapshot before anything happened. However, after it creates:

Error establishing a database connection

At the static IP address I assigned. The instance should contain a localhost copy of the database that was in the snapshot right? If so why would there be an issue connecting to the new instances db given the passwords and users should stay the same.